# Python, Pandas, Filter, memory

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have stacked on applying a filter in Pandas.
In my table, I have 3 columns A, B, Z.
I would like to filter as:
A == "WORK",
B is null,
Z == "A1",

```
final = df[['A','B','Z',]]
  
Z = final[(final['A'] ==('WORK')) & final[(final['B'].isnull())] & (final['Z'] == 'A1')]
Print (Z)
```

If I remove the middle section- it works.
If I run only the middle section - it works.
But when I used all 3 parameters - it eats all my RAM 16Gb then stuck..

Comment: why do you have `final[(final['B'].isnull())]` instead of `(final['B'].isnull())` only

Comment: thanks for your comment!
I have removed extra staff from the code as you advised.
Now code not eating all memory!

but the final results show 0
(even though I have values "work" in column A, blank in B and value "work" at Z.

Comment: youre welcome. but i wouldnt know the reason for that because you have the data not me. But if not a typo, you said "value work at Z" but your code checks "A1" not "work" for Z column

Comment: Many thanks for your help.
Yes, it was a typo. Now checked the filter options and found why it was not working. ( Because incorrect filter options)
Again, many thanks!